# Command to output file content to stdout?

Tags: cat, less, stdout

I know [`cat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) can do this, but its main purpose is to concatenate rather than just to display the content.

I also know about [`less`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) and [`more`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html), but I'm looking for something simple (**not a pager**) that just outputs the content of a file to the terminal and it's made specifically for this, if there is such thing.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The most obvious one is `cat`. But also have a look at [`head`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) and [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).

There are other shell utilities to print a file line by line: [`sed`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html), [`awk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html), [`grep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html). But those are meant to manipulate the file content or to search inside the file.

I made a few tests to estimate which is the most effective one. I ran all trough [`strace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to see which made the fewest system calls. My file has 1275 lines.

- `awk`: 1355 system calls
- `cat`: 51 system calls
- `grep`: 1337 system calls
- `head`: 93 system calls
- `tail`: 130 system calls
- `sed`: 1378 system calls

As you can see, even if `cat` was designed to concatenate files, it is the fastest and most effective one. `sed`, `awk` and `grep` printed the file line by line, that's why they have more that 1275 system calls.

Comment: Good idea to count the syscalls!

Comment: using the command `dd iflag=nonblock status=none if=/path/to/file` is right on par with the `cat` command, in terms of speed but it uses 400% more syscalls. `dd` and `cat` are part of `coreutils` on archlinux. In my tests, `cat` does about 49 syscalls, whereas `dd` does  500+. If you examine the syscalls, you will see that cat does only 3 read calls, while `dd` does 250+, which means cat is doing more buffering than `dd`. I'm sure `dd` can be further tweaked to squeeze out more performance. I just wanted to show that syscalls is not the best metric for something like this if speed is a factor.

Comment: Btw for anyone wondering, the stats I got were measured with `strace --summary-only <command here>`

Comment: `zsh`'s `sysread -b 1000000 -o1` builtin only does 3 system calls (one mmap() to allocate 1M+ of memory, one read, one write). Does that make it a better one?

Comment: Of those, `awk`, `grep` and `sed` are text utilties so can only be used on text files anyway.

Answer (score 26):

> I know `cat` can do this, but its main purpose is to concatenate rather than just displaying the content.

The purpose of `cat` is exactly that, read a file and output to stdout.

Comment: But ```cat --help``` says "Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output". I don't wanna concatenate anything

Comment: Believe it or not, cat is exactly what you're looking for anyway.

Comment: It isn't though. Surely the UNIX philosophy "Make each program do one thing well. To do a new job, build afresh rather than complicate old programs by adding new features." can help with a tool made specifically for outputting text and nothing else?

Comment: No,@confused00, Jan's right. The thing is - the terminal *is* stdout - you see? do `readlink /dev/fd/1` for example - you should get your tty's name in there if running at a standard prompt. So concatenating input to output is what you're asking to do.

Comment: @mikeserv Yeah, I see your point, I guess I was too fixed on the 'concatenate' meaning.

Comment: The logic is, printing the contents of *one* file is just a special case of printing the contents of *one or more* files in sequence.

Comment: @Jan: I disagree that "the purpose of cat is exactly that": it's broader (to concatenate, as the name implies), and outputing a single file to stdout is a nice side effect of that. see my comment to confused00.

Comment: Correct, the answer is simplified, but more details would IMHO have confused the user.

Answer (score 13):

First, `cat` writes to the standard output, which is not necessarily a terminal, even if `cat` was typed as part of a command to an interactive shell. If you really need something to write to the terminal even when the standard output is redirected, that is not so easy (you need to specify which terminal, and there might not even be one if the command is executed from a script), though one could (ab)use the standard error output if the command is merely a part of a pipeline. But since you indicated that `cat` actually does the job, I suppose you were not asking about such a situation.

If your purpose were to send what is written to the standard output into a pipeline, then using `cat` would be eligible to the [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html), since `cat file | pipeline` (where `pipeline` stands for any pipeline) can be done more efficiently as `<file pipeline`. But again, from your wording I deduce that this was not your intention.

So it is not so clear what you are worrying about. If you find `cat` too long to type, you can define a one- or two-character alias (there are still a few such names that remain unused in standard Unix). If however you are worrying
that `cat` is spending useless cycles, you shouldn't.

If there were a program `null` that takes no arguments and just copies standard input to standard output (the neutral object for pipelines), you could do what you want with `<file null`. There is no such program, though it would be easy to write (a C program with just a one-line `main` function can do the job), but calling `cat` without arguments (or `cat -` if you like to be explicit) does just that.

If there were a `nocat` program that takes exactly one filename argument, tries to open the file, complains it if cannot, and otherwise proceeds to copy from the file to the standard output, then that would be just what you are asking for. It is only slightly harder to write than `null`, the main work being opening the file, testing, and possibly complaining (if you are meticulous, you may also want to include a test that there is exacly one argument, and complain otherwise). But again `cat`, now provided with a single argument, does just that, so there is no need for any `nocat` program.

Once you succeeded in writing the `nocat` program, why stop at a single argument? Wrapping the code into a loop `for(;*argp!=NULL;++argp)` is really no effort at all, adds at most a couple of machine instructions to the binary, and avoids having to complain about a wrong number of arguments (which spares many more instructions). Voilà a primitive version of `cat`, concatenating files. (To be honest you need to tweak it a little bit so that without arguments it behaves as `null`.)

Of course in the real `cat` program, they added a few bells and whistles, because they always do. But the essence is that the "concatenation" aspect of `cat` costs really no effort at all, neither for the programmer nor for the machine executing it. The fact that `cat` subsumes `null` and `nocat` explains the nonexistence of such programs. Avoid using `cat` with a single argument if the result goes into a pipeline, but if it is used just for displaying file contents on the terminal, even the page I linked to admits that this is a useful use of `cat`, so don't hesitate.

---

You may test that `cat` is really implemented by a simple loop around a hypthetical `nocat` functionality, by calling `cat` with several file names among which one invalid name, not in the first position: rather than complaining right away that this file does not exists, `cat` first dumps the preceeding valid files, and then complains about the invalid file (at least that is how my cat behaves).

Answer (score 11):

Under `zsh` try

```
<file
```

I believe it is the shortest way to print a file.
It uses 'hidden' `cat` (or `more` if stdout is a terminal), but the command used for printing is controlled by `READNULLCMD` variable which you can safely overwrite directly by command name or even by some function. For example to print files with line numbering:

```
numcat() { nl -s'> ' -w2 - }
READNULLCMD=numcat
<file
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a past tense question.  Technically, since printing the contents of a file to `stdout` is a form of concatenation, `cat` is semantically appropriate.  Don't forget that `printf` is semantically intended to format and print data.  Bash also provides syntax to redirect input and output from files.  A combination of these might produce this:

```sh
printf '%s' "$(<file.txt)"
```

Comment: Apart from being particularly roundabout, the command displayed is not equivalent to `cat file.txt`, since it will remove any trailing newlines (the `$(...)` does this).

Answer (score 5):

POSIX define [cat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html#tag_20_13_03) as:

> **NAME**
>
> cat - concatenate and print files
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> cat [-u] [file...]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The cat utility shall read files in sequence and shall write their
>   contents to the standard output in the same sequence.

So I think *concatenate* here means *read files in sequence*.

Answer (score 5):

Just as a demonstration, you can do

```
cp foo /dev/stdout
```

Comment: Be careful using this when building a container environment with something like docker or podman. The file descriptors in the containers are usually owned by root so attempting to do any writes or reads with an unprivileged user directly from any of those files will result in permission denied. See this issue on [github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31243)

Answer (score 4):

Using `bash` builtins and avoiding subprocess creation:

```
{ while IFS='' read -rd '' _bcat_; do printf '%s\0' "${_bcat_}"; done; printf '%s' "${_bcat_}"; unset _bcat_; } <'/path/to/file'
```

`IFS` will be applied only to `read` command, so do not worry about your global `IFS` changes.

Loop required to handle null characters (thanks to Stéphane Chazelas
).

This way is not suitable for big files because file content read to the variable (so memory) first. BTW I've tried to print 39M text file this way and bash memory usage did not exceed 5M, so not sure about this case.

It also damn slow and CPU inefficient: for the same 39M file it took ~3 minutes with 100% usage of single core.

For big files or binaries better to use `cat '/path/to/file'` or even `dd if='/path/to/file' bs=1M` if possible.

Comment: See also `pv -q` which on Linux can use `splice()` which for some types of stdin/stdout will improve performances.